# UIImageView Transition Betwen Multiple Images

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks

I am using the below code to change the UIImageView's image after a short duration. The images being used are stored in an array as you can see.

The problem is, no matter what 'duration' or 'delay' I set, the imageview changes almost instantly to the last image in the array.

Should I instead be using the main thread to add a delay between each image transition?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 animationCount = 0;
 imageArray =[NSMutableArray new];
 [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gauge1final.png"]];
 [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gauge2final.png"]];
 [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gauge3final.png"]];
 [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gauge4final.png"]];
 [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gauge5final.png"]];
 [self multiStageAnimate];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

-(void) multiStageAnimate{
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:5.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^
                 {
                     self.gauge.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:animationCount];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     animationCount ++;

                     if(animationCount < imageArray.count){
                         [self multiStageAnimate];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         animationCount = 0;
                     }
                 }];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIImageView` does have a mechanism to accomplish your need.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"], nil];
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 means repeat without stop.
imageView.animationDuration = 1.5; // Animation duration

[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: This method has any delaying property like UIView Animation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple screens with the same animation, it's better to create one **.plist** file and then use this anywhere in your project. The steps are as follows:

1. First, generate one .plist file **File-> New File-> Resource ->Property List**

   [image]
2. Write your code like this:

   **ViewController.h**

   ```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dataImageView;
   ```

   **ViewController.m**

   ```
   NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PhotesArray" ofType:@"plist"]];
   NSArray *imageNames = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"Photos"];
   NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int i=0; i<[imageNames count]; i++) {
       [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
   }
   //Normal animation
   self.dataImageView.animationImages = images;
   self.dataImageView.animationDuration = 5.0;
   [self.dataImageView startAnimating];
   ```

Answer (score -2):

The image property of a UIImageView won't animate. What you need to do is have 2 UIImageView widgets one on top of another. Then, you can animate their alpha properties from 0 to 1 (and vice-versa) with each transition.