# Is there a way to return something every time a for loop repeats without ever exiting the loop in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to have lots of images have momentum after one image is panned, to make this the most simple I would use some sort of for loop to give the UIView.animate the animation data for the images, but if I return the data for one of the images to work the for loop ends. The only other idea I had was to have an array to store these values and to return that, but I have no idea the type of variable that would store this. Sorry I am very new to Swift and I honestly don't know what half of these things are called, but hopefully with the code you can understand what I am trying to do.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(vectorToFinalPointLength/1800) ,delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            for (i,item) in self.ClosetItems.enumerated() {
                return item.center.x = finalPointCloset[i]
            }
        })
```

the animations: wants multiple  statements, but since the return ends the entire for loop it only gets one of the 30 in the array.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if you just delete the word `return`?

Comment: Is this what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042339/2193968

Comment: Have you tried using Generators?

Comment: Why do you need 30 statements in the first place? You seem to be attempting to define your own key frames of this animation, but normally that's not needed. You only need to say where the `item` ends up at. Are you trying to move `item` a long a custom path as defined by `finalPointCloset`, as opposed to a straight path from one point to another?

Comment: when you use return it will finish you loop.
if you want return something every time you can use Timer and set repeat time to call your code

Comment: The reason you can’t just remove return is I don’t think it recognizes the command then

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: TimeInterval(vectorToFinalPointLength / 1800),
    delay: 0, 
    options: .curveEaseOut,
    animations: {
        self.ClosetItems.enumerated().forEach { i, item in
            item.center.x = finalPointCloset[i]
        }
    }
)
```